# Security error in cross domain iframe

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, ssl

I have a click tracker for a client. The tracker is nothing but a javascript snippet which writes an iframe(a different domain) into the page.

If I have a normal iframe I am able to track clicks more accuratley(I compare the data from another tracking solution) than when the iframe is secure(the site is accessed over ssl).

While trying to debug the issue, I came across a scenario, where the iframe had a security error. It said something to the extent that the Secure Certificate was not Valid.

The problem now is, I could see this error only once, after which I could not reproduce it. Is there any way I can replicate the error? Is there any way I can figure out why I am tracking less clicks if the iframe is secured?

**Technology Stack**:
dotNet framework 3.5
OS: Win 2003 server
Web server: IIS 6.0
SSL Certificate Issuer: Go Daddy.

Answer (score 1):

iframes should be sharing the same domain for example foo.com and subdomain.foo.com is not the same SSL wise.

Comment: yes, I understand that. In this case we are placing the snippet from a different domain. So this situation does not arise.

Comment: If you are placing the snippet from another domain then you are already violating same-domain policy. Did you try including the snippet in the "same" domain ?

Comment: I cannot do that, as I don't have any control over the domain. I can just place this snippet placed on the html page.

Answer (score 1):

The range of permissible access for a page can be expanded when a script assigns the document.domain property to a suffix of the site name space, up to the second-level domain. For example, a page on www.microsoft.com can assign the document.domain property—initially www.microsoft.com—as microsoft.com to broaden access to include pages in home.microsoft.com or any other site, as long as the other pages also set the document.domain property to the identical value.
[About Cross-Frame Scripting and Security : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028(VS.85).aspx)